# Path finding in java / prolog using A*Star

Tags: java, prolog, path-finding, a-star

I am supposed to start for example from point 1B to 5D. how am i supposed to reach? anyone can gv me a hint to get start on this?thanks. not asking for codes but the tips/ hints. thanks.

```
  A B C D E 
1 5 1 4 4 1
2 3 4 3 3 4
3 4 3 1 1 3
4 4 3 4 2 5 
5 3 4 1 1 3
```

Comment: At the very least form some complete sentences.

Comment: By going down 4 times and then to the right 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining data structures , and apply algorithm with it

You may refer to pseudo-code on wiki: [Wiki A Star Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

Comment: Manhatten-Distance is the heuristic you probably want to use for your A*